# Pytorch equivalent features in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pytorch

I recently was reading a Pytorch code and came across `loss.backward()` and `optimizer.step()` functions, are there any equivalent of these using tensorflow/keras?

Answer (score 13):

`loss.backward()` equivalent in tensorflow is `tf.GradientTape()`. TensorFlow provides the `tf.GradientTape` API for automatic differentiation - computing the gradient of computation with respect to its input variables. Tensorflow "records" all operations executed inside the context of a `tf.GradientTape` onto a "tape". Tensorflow then uses that tape and the gradients associated with each recorded operation to compute the gradients of a "recorded" computation using reverse mode differentiation.

`optimizer.step()` equivalent in tensorflow is `minimize()`. Minimizes the loss by updating the variable list. Calling `minimize()` takes care of both computing the gradients and applying them to the variables.

If you want to process the gradients before applying them you can instead use the optimizer in three steps:

1. Compute the gradients with `tf.GradientTape`.
2. Process the gradients as you wish.
3. Apply the processed gradients with `apply_gradients()`.

Hope this answers your question. Happy Learning.

Comment: @Sandipan Banerjee - Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You.

Comment: Yes, that answers my question. But I am unable to upvote due to new account.

Comment: But you can still accept the answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers